# Циклы,js Написать программу, которая выводит таблицу кубов первых десяти целых положительных чисел

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
document.write( 'Число ' + i + ' <br> ' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно таблицу? Тогда так:

```
document.write( '<table>' );
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  document.write( '<tr><td>Число ' + i*i*i + '</td></tr>' );
}
document.write( '</table>' );
```

Похоже на какое-то домашнее задание

Comment: да это дз,основы программирования, спасибо большое

Comment: @VetalDudin если задача решена не забудьте отметить правильный ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

[Куб числа a](http://www.for6cl.uznateshe.ru/kub-chisla/) — это произведение трёх множителей, каждый из которых равен a. Куб числа a обозначают a³. Читают: «a в кубе» или «a в третьей степени». ... Таким образом, чтобы найти куб числа (говорят также «возвести число в куб»), надо это число взять множителем три раза и вычислить полученное произведение.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    document.write( 'Число ' + i*i*i + ' <br> ' );
```

Comment: спасибо большое